# Implementations of chameleon hash functions

Tags: library, cryptography

For a research project we want to build a proof of concept of a redactable blockchain that employs chameleon hashing (cf. https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/757.pdf).

We are looking now for implementations (library) of chameleon hash functions that we could use. Does anyone know of a library that implements chameleon hash functions (any variation of it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for an implementation, I implemented chameleon hashing in GO: https://github.com/julwil/chameleon_hash